Blender and mouse wheel in MacOS Sequoia
I'm newbie in Blender. Installed it a few hours ago and found a problem.
I'm using macOS Sequoia 15.0.1. While I'm trying to move objects in my Viewport window by pressing Mouse Wheel, my Sequoia switch my working location instead of moving objects in Blender. Any gestures I do with my mouse wheel if this gestures are in my macOS - it's done by macOS not by Blender.
